# How to use the call command to validate a password in batch

Tags: batch-file, passwords, command, call

So I have this code

```
@echo off  
set /p pass=Input Pass:  
call rig.txt   
if %pass%==rig.txt goto right  
goto wrong  
:wrong  
echo Authentication Failed!  
pause  
exit  
:right  
echo correct  
pause
```

So instead of having something like this

```
@echo off  
set /p pass=Input Pass:  
if %pass%==randompassword goto right  
goto wrong  
:wrong  
echo Authentication Failed!  
pause  
exit  
:right  
echo correct  
pause
```

Im trying to get it so it calls rig.txt which has my password in it and checks if i inputed the right password. Please help!

Comment: please tell us a bit more about your problem, the more we know the better, it doesn't look like your issue can be diagnosed from what you've provided here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off  

rem Read right password saved in rig.txt file
set /P rightPass=< rig.txt

set /p pass=Input Pass:  
if %pass% == %rightPass% goto right  
echo Authentication Failed!  
pause  
exit  

:right  
echo correct  
pause
```